# reactjs - How to implement onChange handler in map?

Tags: reactjs

I want to have an input box for every attributes under customizeInfo and allow changes. It can perfectly display the data but onChange handler is not working (input control not editable). How can I implement the handler in map?

I have an array of JavaScript objects:

```
customizeInfo: [
    {
        "appId": "App 1",
        "attrSet": {
            "nationality": "American",
            "children": "Morgan Stark",
            "spouse": "Pepper Potts"
        }
    },
    {
        "appId": "App 2",
        "attrSet": {
            "weapon": "Iron Man",
            "assistAI": "F.R.I.D.A.Y"
        }
    }
]
```

My code:

```
render() {
    const {customizeInfo} = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            {
                customizeInfo.map((el) => {
                    return <div>
                        <h5>{el.appId}</h5>
                        <div><input name="nationality" value={el.attrSet.nationality} 
                        onChange={this.onChange}></input></div>
                        <div>{el.attrSet.children}</div>
                    </div>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

OnChange:

```
onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
}
```

Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        customizeInfo: []
}

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 3 ways below:

1. this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this) in constructor
2. onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}>
3. onChange = (event) => {
       this.setState({
           [event.target.name]: event.target.value
       })
   }